# What is the correct way to export SVG in order to convert to STL?

Tags: 3d-design, stl, fusion360

I made a simple logo using Inkscape, after saving as an svg file, but when I export that file into Fusion 360 something strange happened.

Multiple times I convert some images (png, svg) to svg file. The process I use is this:

1. Scan logo image (scanner or smartphone)
2. Open image with Inkscape
3. Using the stroke, generate the shape
4. All process for generate and save

This process explained above always works for me, when I copy the shape using the *stroke* in Inkscape.

However, when I was do the process using the *shape generator* - for example, rectangles, circles, squares, etc. - and export the file into the Fusion 360, it doesn't work.

#### 1 - Inkscape logo

[image: inkscape]

#### 2 - Logo import to Fusion 360

[image: Import into Fusion 360]

In the example above, the first word does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the simplicity of your sample design - i.e. basically only two different Z-levels, easily distinguished by color - I'd recommend one of the online image-to-3D model converters.  Here are two I've used now and then.  You may have to save your image as png or jpg instead of svg.

[selva3d](https://www.selva3d.com/)   and [3dp.rocks](http://3dp.rocks/lithophane/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but is so limited. The results are these, [model's link](https://imgur.com/a/1aZUdUV)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use Fusion 360. So I will answer for that, based on [Autodesk Help](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/fusion-360/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-import-SVG-files-in-Fusion-360.html):

### Make the SVG

You need to design your SVG to be **just** the **outlines** of your logo. That you can easily do in Inkscape by [setting the fill to transparent](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67532). Then you need to define a size before [exporting](https://gist.github.com/brenopolanski/46cd370d634a1709aa8a58e55cfc9a03) it properly.

### Import the SVG

- `Insert` Menu

  - `Insert SVG`
- Select the plane you want to put the SVG on
- Select the folder icon

  - choose the SVG
- adjust the sizing and positioning
- `OK`

Comment: Thanks, but i do that, i think the problem come from the method i do for make the logo. I go to see some videos about to use inkscape.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales it might be your process of creating and exporting the SVG that is flawed. [Exporting](https://gist.github.com/brenopolanski/46cd370d634a1709aa8a58e55cfc9a03) is rather straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for your recomendation, i will try to use the save as copy option.